# Removing element from array error

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, joptionpane

In the following code, if the size of the array is larger than 20, I'm trying to remove anything after 20 from the array. In my loop, I have userinput.remove(20 + i);      However, I'm getting that it can't find the symbol remove? I'm not sure why it's doing this if the error.add itself is actually working.

**userinput is defined earlier in the code**

```
public static void checknames(String[] userinput){

ArrayList<String> error = new ArrayList<String> ();


    if(userinput.length > 20){

        for(int i=0; i<userinput.length - 20; i++){
            error.add(userinput[20 + i]);
            userinput.remove(20 + i);}
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can only enter up to 20
            employees. \n The following employees exceed this limit." + error);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is correct - there is no such `remove` method for arrays.  You should either:

- Use a `List` instead, like the `ArrayList` you have used for `error`.
- Create a new array which is 1 element shorter, and copy over everything except the element you are trying to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `remove` an array.  You can't change the size of the array.  But you could set that element to `null`:

```
userinput[20 + i] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userinput.remove(20 + i);
```

`userinput` is array of `String[]`. There is not method `remove(..)` available for array.

May be you need to set value to `null` for indexes greater than 20 (or) create a new `String` array with only first 20 elements and discard `userinput`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void checknames(String[] userinput) {

    List<String> error = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=20; i<userinput.length; i++) {
            error.add(userinput[i]);
            userinput[i] = null;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can only enter up to 20
            employees. \n The following employees exceed this limit." + error);

}
```

Just a few little changes. You should always make `ArrayList`s like this(with `List<...>`) on the left-hand side. Also, I got rid of the `if` statement and slightly changed your loop so you don't need it. And as everyone else mentioned, `.remove(...)` doesn't work with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on keeping the String[], you could delegate the "dirty work" to existing API methods, i.e. [Arrays.copyOfRange(Object[] src, int from, int to)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

---

Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class R {
    public static String[] trimEmployees(String[] employees, int maxSize) {
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(employees, 0, maxSize);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] employees = new String[] { "Jennifer", "Paul", "Tori",
                "Zulema", "Donald", "Aleshia", "Melisa", "Angelika", "Elda",
                "Elenor", "Kimber", "Eusebia", "Mike", "Karyn", "Marinda",
                "Titus", "Miki", "Alise", "Liane", "Suzanne", "Dorothy" };
        int max = 20;

        System.out.println(String.format("Input employees (len=%d): %s ",
                employees.length, Arrays.toString(employees)));
        if (employees.length > max) {
            employees = trimEmployees(employees, max);
            System.out.println(String.format("Trimmed employees (len=%d): %s",
                    employees.length, Arrays.toString(employees)));
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Input employees (len=21): [Jennifer, Paul, Tori, Zulema, Donald, Aleshia, Melisa, Angelika, Elda, Elenor, Kimber, Eusebia, Mike, Karyn, Marinda, Titus, Miki, Alise, Liane, Suzanne, Dorothy] 
Trimmed employees (len=20): [Jennifer, Paul, Tori, Zulema, Donald, Aleshia, Melisa, Angelika, Elda, Elenor, Kimber, Eusebia, Mike, Karyn, Marinda, Titus, Miki, Alise, Liane, Suzanne]
```